Celery task shows success in Flower but is still pending and not executed
I am using Celery with Django. My broker is Redis, and the task results are stored in the database.
I run Celery using the following command:
celery -A core worker -Q celery,send_sms --autoscale=10,0 -l INFO  

When I execute a Celery task with :
res = send_sms.apply_async(
                kwargs=dict(mobile=self.mobile, text=self.text, master_id=master_id, send_as_service=send_as_service,
                            high_priority=high_priority))

Flower status's is  SUCCESS. However, when I check the task status with:
AsyncResult("395b43ce-ee48-4e6d-937b-922e1bc8d377").state  

the state remains PENDING.
In reality, the task has not been executed yet.
my celery setting:
CELERY_BROKER_URL = redis://redis:6379/0
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = django-db

CELERY_RESULT_EXTENDED = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'sms.tasks.send_sms': {'queue': 'send_sms'},
}

The Celery task is expected to execute immediately.
However, the task remains in the PENDING state instead of being executed.
